# Up and down versions of \rangle and \langle

Tags: symbols

Latex has these:

[image]

Are they "up" and "down" equivalents of the above? That is, each of the above simply rotated anticlockwise by 90°.

Comment: You can always use `\rotatebox` from the `graphicx` package.

Comment: \widehat might work.